# Sorting on list values read into a list from a file

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to write a routine to read values from a text file, (names and scores) and then be able to sort the values az by name, highest to lowest etc. I am able to sort the data but only by the position in the string, which is no good where names are different lengths. This is the code I have written so far:

```
ClassChoice = input("Please choose a class to analyse Class 1 = 1, Class 2 = 2")
if ClassChoice == "1":
    Classfile = open("Class1.txt",'r')
else:
    Classfile = open("Class2.txt",'r')
ClassList = [line.strip() for line in Classfile]
ClassList.sort(key=lambda s: s[x])
print(ClassList)
```

This is an example of one of the data files (Each piece of data is on a separate line):

Bob,8,7,5
Fred,10,9,9
Jane,7,8,9
Anne,6,4,8
Maddy,8,5,5
Jim, 4,6,5
Mike,3,6,5
Jess,8,8,6
Dave,4,3,8
Ed,3,3,4

I can sort on the name, but not on score 1, 2 or 3. Something obvious probably but I have not been able to find an example that works in the same way.

Thanks

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking. What do you mean _not on score 1, 2, 3_?

Comment: So you have a list of name, followed by some values, and you want the lines to be sorted by name and then within each line, you want the values to also be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
indexToSortOn = 0 # will sort on the first integer value of each line
classChoice = ""
while not classChoice.isdigit():
    classChoice = raw_input("Please choose a class to analyse (Class 1 = 1, Class 2 = 2) ")
classFile = "Class%s.txt" % classChoice
with open(classFile, 'r') as fileObj:
    classList = [line.strip() for line in fileObj]
classList.sort(key=lambda s: int(s.split(",")[indexToSortOn+1]))
print(classList)
```

The key is to specify in the key function that you pass in what part of each string (the line) you want to be sorting on:

```
classList.sort(key=lambda s: int(s.split(",")[indexToSortOn+1]))
```

The cast to an integer is important as it ensures the sort is numeric instead of alphanumeric (e.g. 100 > 2, but "100" < "2")

Comment: Thanks guys a combination of this and wmckevitt has fixed the sorting of string objects now I just need to sort within the sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking.  I am not a sort expert, but here goes:

Assuming you would like the ability to sort the lines by either the name, the first int, second int or third int, you have to realize that when you are creating the list, you aren't creating a two dimensional list, but a list of strings.  Due to this, you may wish to consider changing your lambda to something more like this:

```
ClassList.sort(key=lambda s: str(s).split(',')[x])
```

This assumes that the x is defined as one of the fields in the line with possible values 0-3.

The one issue I see with this is that list.sort() may sort Fred's score of 10 as being less than 2 but greater than 0 (I seem to remember this being how sort worked on ints, but I might be mistaken).

Comment: Cheers - this with a tweak from the above answer sorted it thanks :0)